# Parsing datestring in format "dd/mm/yyyy" in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I can't parse the simplest date string for some reason. the following is giving me 'invalid date'.

```
 moment.locale('en-gb');
 var tempDate = moment("23/07/2018").format("DD/MM/YYYY");
```

this doesn't work either:

```
 moment.locale('en-gb');
 var tempDate = moment("23/07/2018");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [String+Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) version of the `moment` function:

```
moment("23/07/2018", "DD/MM/YYYY")
```

Comment: @BMills if you set "en-gb" locale, you can use "L" format `moment("23/07/2018", "L")`

Answer (score 3):

```js
var mydate= moment("23/07/2018","DD/MM/YYYY").format("DD/MM/YYYY");
console.log(mydate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I fail to see how this answer is any different than the one already posted 5 minutes ago....

Comment: they were likely typing at the same time